# Orbital period of a satellite in Kerbal Space Program

Tags: orbital-motion, space, celestial-mechanics

Let me start off by saying I am really bad at maths and physics, but lately I have been trying to calculate the orbital period of a satellite I have put in orbit around a planet called Kerbin in a game called Kerbal Space Program. The only resources I have are online formulas that I have to decode and understand myself, without anyone's help.

I find it really fun but at the same time frustrating. I've always had terrible teachers when it comes to physics, so I was never able to force myself to learn the material properly. Thus forgive me if I seem to be ignorant in that matter but I am really trying to improve.

I tried using this formula:

```
T = 2pi * sqrt(a^3/GM)
```

My periapse (`r2`) is 2.863265 * 10^6 [m], adding the radius of the planet to this number I get 2.869265 * 10^6 [m]. The apoapse (`r1`) together with that exact same radius equals to 2.869436 * 10^6 [m].

Now I have to plug those numbers into the equation:

```
a = (r1+r2)/2

a = 2.8693505 * 10^6 [m]    

a^3 = 2.36238570322 * 10^19

G = 6.67408 * 10^(-11)

M = 5.2915793 * 10^22 [kg]

GM = 3.00248442745 * 10^12
```

**My question is - am I approaching this correctly? Will I get a correct period using those calculations? What units will be used for the period? Seconds? Hours?**

Comment: Your approach is correct, since is good for satellites in circular orbits around much heavier masses. You forgot to write the units of the [gravitational constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant) which judging from your value, is given in $N (m/kg)^2$ or $m^3/(s^2kg)$ so your result should be in units of seconds.

Comment: Would this calculation work for eliptical orbits?

Comment: @Pe-Ter A little late for this party, but for you and future readers, yes, you can use it for elliptical orbits. The eccentricity of the orbit doesn't matter, as long as the semi-major axis ('`a`') stays the same.